# How to check the current state in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular-ui-router in my application. 
I want to check the current state where the user is and show the same in the view. When i use "$state.current.name" it is giving error "name is not defined".
Below is my code please check

**headerCntroller.js**

```
angular.module("adminsuite").controller("headerController",['AuthenticationService','$state','$rootScope','$cookieStore','$scope',function(AuthenticationService,$rootScope,$cookieStore,$scope,$state){
      $scope.header = $state.current.name;

      $rootScope.global = {
        search: '',
        newsurvey: false
      };
     $scope.logout = function(){
                //$scope.dataLoading = true;
                AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
                console.log($cookieStore.get('globals'));
                //$state.go('login');
            };
  }]);
```

Comment: Add `<pre>{{state | json}}</pre>` to your DOM if you wish to visualize your state

Comment: Do you have name property defined in your state?